# Duplicating .blank? in standard Ruby

Tags: ruby

Rails has a .blank? method that will return true if an Object is empty? or nil?. The actual code for this can be found [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb#L12). When I try on 1.9.2 to duplicate this by doing:

```
class Object

  def blank?
    respond_to?(:empty?) ? empty? : !self
  end

end
```

Calling "".blank? returns true but calling " ".blank? returns false when according to the [rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) a whitespace string should eval to true for .blank? Before I looked up the code I originally wrote:

```
class Object

  def blank?
    !!self.empty? || !!self.nil?
  end

end
```

and had the same results. What am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You forget about this - https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb#L95

```
class String
  # A string is blank if it's empty or contains whitespaces only:
  #
  #   "".blank?                 # => true
  #   "   ".blank?              # => true
  #   " something here ".blank? # => false
  #
  def blank?
    self !~ /\S/
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what I get for not having access to grep right now. I'll mark you as the answer asap.

Answer (score 2):

The `String` class overrides the `Object` implementation of `blank?` in Rails's implementation:

```
class String

  def blank?
    # Blank if this String is not composed of characters other than whitespace.
    self !~ /\S/ 
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are not classed as `empty?` if they are full of spaces only

```
>> "  ".empty?
=> false
```

Therefore, you may wish to also create

```
class String
  def blank?
    strip.empty?
  end
end
```

But think carefully about this - monkey patching like this is hazardous, especially if other modules will use your code.

Comment: Will keep this in mind for the future. Right now I'm just learning more about Ruby and toying with .blank? in IRB.